# How many values of c is the derivative of the function equal to its average rate of change?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

My guess is that there is only one value of c that makes the limit of the function c equal (derivative) to its average rate of change at c but I am not sure.

[image]

[image]

The graph of a function $f$ with $f(b) > f(a)$ is shown above for $a≤x≤b$. The derivative of $f$ exists for all $x$ in the interval $a<x<b$ except $x=0$.

For how many values of $c$, for $a<c<b$ does $\lim\limits_{x \to c} \dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ equal $\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$?

Comment: That is very small print, so you should type it out in LaTeX.  I suspect $1$ is also too small

Comment: @Henry I typed the question.

Comment: LaTeX would be easier to read

Comment: @Henry I've got an idea but I am not sure if this is correct. According to the Mean Value theorem, If function $f$ is continuous over $[a,b]$ and is differentiable  over $(a,b)$, then there exists a value $c$ such that the derivative of $f$ at $c$ equals its average rate of change. The given function is not differential at all the values over the open interval. Does that mean there's no such $c$ value?

Comment: I would have thought for the particular $f$ shown there is more than one such $c$.  For a different $f$ there might not be any

Comment: @Henry If that's the case, there would be I think 4 values of c somewhere at the local minima except the of course the absolute minimum at 0 of the graph.

Comment: For $f(x)=|x|$ on $(-1,2)$ there is no such $c$.

Comment: For $f(x)=|x|^{3}$ on (-1,2) there are exactly two values of $c$.

Comment: I would have thought $4$ might be correct too.  @KaviRamaMurthy's first example was the kind of thing I was thinking about as a counterexample

Comment: @Henry so 4 is not right?

Comment: It depends on the original question being particular or general.  I would have said $4$

Comment: @Henry That is the question. there are actually choices: zero, two, three or four.

Comment: @Henry I just can't say whether the function is differentiable over the open interval $(a,b)$. If not, the mean value theorem won't work right? But since the graph is given, I wold say there must be at most 4 values.

Comment: The Mean Value Theorem does not tell you **how many** values of $c$ there will be. It only tells you that there will be **at least one** value of $c$.